# Distorted Cabins & Oily Sheens: What happens really when a low rumble comes?

Tags: meaning

For this text:

> There came a low rumble, which distorted the cabin around her, and cast an oily sheen on the walls.

Could you tell me that what happened really here as the above text says?In this way?---

There came a low rumble,then distorted the cabin?----

[image]

(let's suppose that's the cabin of the ship on the picture...)

and then?---

[image]

(let's suppose that's the walls on the picture. And an oily sheen on the walls like this on the picture?)

Can it really happen like this? A sound as a low rumble can be so powerful to distort the cabin slightly?

Thank you in advance!

The context is :

> "I can see nothing."     There came a low rumble, which distorted the cabin around her, and cast an oily sheen on the walls. "Watch."

---

Excerpted from Aliette de Bodard's novel "The Two Sisters in Exile" partly(maybe you needn't read these words) :

> "We're here," The Tortoise in the Lake said, cutting across Dong Huong's gloomy thoughts.
>    "I can see nothing."
>   There came a low rumble, which distorted the cabin around her, and cast an oily sheen on the walls. "Watch."
>    Outside, everything was dark. There was only the shadow of The Two Sisters in Exile, the dead ship that they'd been pulling since Longevity Station.